# Pass an NSMutableArray to a NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nswindowcontroller

So I am creating a NSWindowController like so:

```
if ( summaryWindow ) {
    [summaryWindow release];
} // end if
summaryWindow   = [[SummaryWindowController alloc] init];
```

I am then passing this object an array that I will be using for a NSTableView

```
[ summaryWindow setGlobalStatusArray:globalStatusArray];
```

Once that object is created, I realize I have don't know how to do something fundamental which is to link the newly created object actions and outlets. If I create a object in the xib, and link up the methods, I can run an action but I don't have access to the array because the xib created a separate instance of the NSWindowController, so how would one programmatically create the NSWindowController but also pass an array to it.

Comment: FYI this was discovered by this question if it helps for some context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111771/issue-with-nsmutablearray-visibility-retain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just ended up doing this via NSNotifications, and passing the Information via the userInfo.

```
// Register for notifications on Global Status Array updates
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadTableBuffer:) 
                                                 name:StatusUpdateNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Like so:

```
- (void) reloadTableBuffer:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if(debugEnabled)NSLog(@"DEBUG: Was Told to Reload Table Buffer...");
    NSDictionary *globalStatusUpdate = [notification userInfo];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to initialize the windowcontroller properly. `[[SummaryWindowController alloc] init];` just creates an empty window controller that doesn't know its window an so on. 
You can load it with its xib file. Do it like this:

```
summaryWindow   = [[SummaryWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"YourWindowNIB"];
```

Comment: So I have a NSLog in my awakeFromNib override,and I still even with the code modification there still see two messages, which would indicate that there are still two distinct objects. 1 that I am init, and one in that init with the xib loads.

Comment: Why do you initialize two objects? Just initialize one with the xib and you're done.

Comment: That was I guess the root of my question, I have add an object in interface builder and set it as the same class, so that I can link the actions up. I am creating the window from another object thus the code above, I fundamentally just need to know how to init a new window controller and pass a NSMutableArray to the object in the xib . While I could load the window for a single object I was trying to keep things seperate.

Comment: I guess put a different way, I don't know a mechanism of passing a data between the object that loads a nib and the object instantiated by the nib when its loaded.

Comment: Also just a heads up I was already using if ( ! (self = [super initWithWindowNibName: @"SummaryWindow"]) in my init of the window, which I think would basically do the same thing.

Comment: okay i think i got it. you should add @property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet SummaryWindowController* summaryWindowController; to the header file of the object that passes the array to the controller. The you can connect this property in the nib with the object. call [summaryWindowController setGlobalStatusArray:globalStatusArray]; to pass the array.

Comment: I will try that, but I am wondering if owner might do what I want to?

Comment: (id)initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName owner:(id)owner

Comment: Per your suggestion, how exactly do I link the property in interface builder, as the nib does not contain the original object?